# Action works everywhere except Google Home on iOS

Tags: actions-on-google

I have a pretty basic conversational action built in Actions Console and Dialogflow, it's published publicly in the directory.

No surface capability requirements, so it should be available on all surfaces according to Actions Console.

I'm able to invoke the action on my Google Home Mini, on Google Assistant and Google Home on Android, on Google Assistant on iOS, but not on Google Home on iOS. There I only get the error "Sorry,  isn't supported on this device."

And we get customer complaining this as well, so it's not a one-off with my account. I've also used the same account across all surfaces when testing. Any ideas what can cause this behaviour?

Comment: So it works in the Google Assistant app but not the Google Home app when using iOS?

Comment: Exactly. Pretty weird, I would've thought they were pretty thin frontends to the same functionality when it comes to the speech assistant